# if statement not working in Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, syntax-error

I can't understand why this simple `if` statement to check whether a string is empty is not working. It's giving me:

> syntax error near unexpected token `then'

```
#!/bin/bash
str="Hello World!"
if[ ! -z "$str"]; then
    echo "str is not empty"
fi
```

I tried it on my PC and an [online editor](https://www.jdoodle.com/test-bash-shell-script-online) as well but it shows the same issue. Any idea?

Comment: Missing space before `[` and before `]`

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[[ ]]` is better than `[ ]` for tests:

```
#!/bin/bash

str="Hello World!"
if [[ ! -z $str ]]; then
  echo "str is not empty"
fi
```

---

Shorter form:

```
#!/bin/bash

str="Hello World!"
[[ ! -z $str ]] && echo "str is not empty"
```

Comment: Its still showing syntax error, can you try it on this [link](https://www.jdoodle.com/test-bash-shell-script-online)online editor[link]

Comment: @Bosco I just checked using the online editor - it worked.  In fact, I pasted my answer after making sure it worked :)

Comment: Ohk thanks i double checked

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash
str="Hello World!"
if [ ! -z "$str" ]; then
    echo "str is not empty"
fi
```

Maybe,
insert space after "if" statement.
and, before "]".